# How to reenable accessibility options?

Tags: bug, accessibility, macos

For some unknown reason NONE of my accessibility options seem to work. I'm trying to enable `Invert Color Display` for example but checking or unchecking the box in system preferences has no effect whatsoever.  Nor does checking any of the other options.

See screenshot showing that options have been selected in system preferences, but all options are greyed out in menu bar drop down.

[image]